# Skydrive android API - move to root folder

Tags: android, api, onedrive

My problem is that, I can't move or copy files to the root folder "me/skydrive" from other folders. I use the android API's LiveConnectClient.moveAsync() method, where the destination folder_id is "me/skydrive".

I get this response:

> The value of input resource ID parameter 'destination' isn't valid.
>   The expected value for this parameter is a resource ID for one of
>   these types: 'folder'.

Is that allowed to move or copy files to the root folder via the REST api? Is it possible to achive this via the Android API?

Answer (score 1):

If you set the id of the root folder, the move operation execute correctly, it's a pitty you have to get the id first